# Getting text enclosed by curly brackets that also contain curly brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea that contains a text string, I am getting its value to a variable named `updatestring`. I am getting the text in this text area that's enclosed by `update(){` and `}`. This text goes into the variable updatecode.

```
var updatestring = 'update(){\n//logic code here...\n\n\n}\n' ;
var updatecode = updatestring.match(/update\(\)\{([^}]+)\}/)[1];
```

The problem I have is that I want to be possible that the text enclosed by  `update(){` and `}` also contain the character `}`. In JavaScript, is there any easy way to do this without using a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greedy matching (which is the default behavior of `*`) will skip over the intermediate `}` characters up to the last one, so nothing special is needed:

```js
var updatestring = 'update(){\n//logic {embedded curly brackets}code here...\n\n\n}\n' ;    

var regexp = /{([^]*)}/;
//            ^                match starting curly
//             ^^^^^^          capture
//              ^^^            any character including newline
//                 ^           any number of times
//                   ^         match ending curly

var regexp = result = updatestring.match(regexp)[1];

console.log(updatestring, result);
```

The `[^]` will match everything including newlines.

By the way, why are you trying to parse something that looks like JavaScript using regexp?

Comment: Good one on the `[^]`, been around regex for some time now and have yet to see anyone actually use that to match all including CRLF. ;)

Comment: An alternative is `[\s\S]`,

Comment: Apparently `[\d\D]` and `[\w\W]` work also, I get the pattern now, lol. ;)

Comment: I am [just sketching](https://ericoporto.github.io/simpleByte/) some ideas of making a processing like / pico8 inspired website. (I know I am using eval, I plan on eventually write an interpreter with jison, but it's enough as is for me to explore the possibilities)

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560720/1236397)'s answer is better, but I'll leave this here to show another way just for educational purposes. ;)*

Try this: `/[^{]*{((?:.|\r|\n)*)}/`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/QOIyvz/4

`[^{]*` - skips all characters until `{` is found and stops just before it.

`{` - matches the first brace.

`((?:.|\r|\n)*)` - `?:` starts a non-capturing group (will not be returned), and `*` "greedily" matches all characters and carriage return and line feeds, and makes them all part of a captured group (between the other `(` and `)`) that is returned.

`}` - Regex will stop the greedy search to match the last one found.

```
Example: updatestring.match(/[^{]*{((?:.|\r|\n)*)}/)[1]
```